# Does snowflake TOP/Limit/Fetch stop processing once it finds enough rows?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

When you use the Snowflake  TOP clause in a query, does the SQL Server engine stop searching for rows once it has enough to satisfy the TOP X needed to be returned?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the rest of your query. For example, if you use `TOP 10` but don't supply an `order by` then yes, it will stop as soon as the 10 records are returned but your results are non-deterministic.

If do you use an `order by`, then the entire query has to be executed first before the top 10 results can be returned but your results will be deterministic.

Here is a real example. If I run a select on the `SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF10000.CUSTOMER` table with a `limit 10` it returns in 1.8 seconds (no caching). This table has 1,500,000,000 rows in it. If I then check the query plan it has only scanned a tiny portion of the table, 1 out of 6,971 partitions:

[image]

You can see that it will return when 10 records have been streamed back from the initial table scan since there is nothing more it has to do.

Comment: i am not applying order by, but i see it still takes the same execution time as without the top clause

Comment: What is your full SQL statement? My explanation about `order by` is just an example of when it would not stop short.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing and understanding, it does not stop. You can see typically see that the last step in the execution plan is the "limit" step. You can also see what's going on by looking at the execution plans. You will typically see the LIMIT (or whatever) after full processing. Also, if you take a query that runs for say 20 seconds without a LIMIT (or similar) and add the LIMIT, you will typically not see any difference in the execution time (but be aware of fetch time).  I typically run query performance testing in the UI to avoid issues with client side tools that can mislead you due to limits on fectching and/or use of cursors.